# How to call a reusable workflow "conditionally" at the job level in github actions

Tags: github

I'm pretty new to GitHub actions, but here's my scenario (in a nutshell)

build-test-upload (job)

-> docker-snapshot (job)

-> docker-release (job) (if: {{github.ref_type == 'tag'}}) -- this job never works

I'm seeing an issue where the "if: {{github.ref_type == 'tag'}}" is not being honored at the job level when the job calls into the reusable workflow 'docker.yml'.  However, if I take everything from 'docker.yml' and add it directly to the build-test-upload.yml workflow as a job, the conditional statement works as expected when there are steps below it.  But my goal is to be able to reuse the docker.yml code for both docker-snapshot and docker-release as seen below.

Does gitHub actions support running jobs conditionally the job calls a reusable workflow?

I apologize if my question is not clear.

thank you

```
name: Build, Test and Upload Artifacts

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:


env:
  ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_GH_USER }}
  ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN }}
  DOCKER_HARBOR_URL: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_ADDR }}
  HARBOR_REPO_BASE: docstore
  APP_ID_DOCSTORE: docstore
  APP_ID_PURGE: purge
  APP_ID_MIGRATION_UTILITY: migration-utility

jobs:
  get-version:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/version.yml

  build-test-upload:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
    needs: [ get-version ]
    outputs:
      version: ${{ needs.get-version.outputs.version }}
    steps: <multiple steps complete successfully>

## docker-snapshot always runs successfully and uses the reusable workflow 'docker.yml' as I would expect
  docker-snapshot:
    name: docker-snapshot
    needs: build-test-upload
    uses: ./.github/workflows/docker.yml
    secrets:
      username: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_USER }}
      token: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_TOKEN }}
      harbor_addr: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_ADDR }}
    with:
      version: ${{ needs.build-test-upload.outputs.version }}
      repo_folder: snapshots

## docker-release is supposed to only run if: github.ref_type == 'tag'.  The "if: ${{ github.ref_type == 'tag' }}" condition works at the job level when the job contains steps, but does not seem to work when docker-release calls the reusable workflow "uses: ./.github/workflows/docker.yml" as seen here

  docker-release:
    if: ${{ github.ref_type == 'tag' }}
    needs: build-test-upload
    uses: ./.github/workflows/docker.yml
    secrets:
      username: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_USER }}
      token: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_TOKEN }}
      harbor_addr: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_ADDR }}
    with:
      version: ${{ needs.build-test-upload.outputs.version }}
      repo_folder: releases
```

docker.yml

```
name: Docker

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      repo_folder:
        required: true
        type: string
      version:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      username:
        required: true
      token:
        required: true
      harbor_addr:
        required: true

env:
  ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_GH_USER }}
  ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN }}
  DOCKER_HARBOR_URL: ${{ secrets.HARBOR_ADDR }}
  HARBOR_REPO_BASE: docstore
  APP_ID_DOCSTORE: docstore
  APP_ID_PURGE: purge
  APP_ID_MIGRATION_UTILITY: migration-utility

jobs:

  docker:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build-test-upload
          path: .

      - name: Verify Artifacts Downloaded
        run: |
          pwd
          VERSION=${{ inputs.version }}
          webserviceFile=./webservice/target/webservice-${VERSION}.jar
          if [[ ! -f "${webserviceFile}" ]]; then
            echo "[ERROR] Webservice jar File ${webserviceFile} does not exist"
            ls -l ./webservice/target
            exit 2
          fi

          purgeFile=./purge/target/purge-${VERSION}.jar
          if [[ ! -f "${purgeFile}" ]]; then
            echo "[ERROR] Purge jar file ${purgeFile}r does not exist"
            ls -l ./purge/target
            exit 2
          fi

          migUtilFile=./migration-utility/target/migration-utility-${VERSION}.jar
          if [[ ! -f ${migUtilFile} ]]; then
            echo "[ERROR] Migration-Utility jar File ${migUtilFile} does not exist"
            ls -l ./migration-utility/target/
            exit 2
          fi

          xmlFile=./tests/target/coverage-report/coverage-report.xml
          csvFile=./tests/target/coverage-report/coverage-report.csv
          if [[ ! -f "${xmlFile}" || ! -f "${csvFile}" ]]; then
            echo "[ERROR] Coverage-report file ${xmlFile} or ${csvFile} does not exist"
            ls -l ./tests/target/coverage-report/
            exit 2
          fi
          echo "Successfully verified build artifacts for dockers were downloaded"

      - name: Create docker context for dind
        run: |
          docker context create dind --docker "host=tcp://localhost:2376,ca=/certs/client/ca.pem,cert=/certs/client/cert.pem,key=/certs/client/key.pem"

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
        with:
          endpoint: dind
          driver: docker-container
          driver-opts: image=docker.apps.papt.to/akp/releases/buildkit:0.9.0-buildx
          buildkitd-flags: --debug

      - name: Harbor Login
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.harbor_addr }}
          username: ${{ secrets.username }}
          password: ${{ secrets.token }}

      - name: Docstore - Docker Build and Push to Harbor ${{ inputs.repo_folder }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.harbor_addr }}/${{ env.HARBOR_REPO_BASE }}/${{ inputs.repo_folder }}/${{ env.APP_ID_DOCSTORE }}:${{ inputs.version }}
          build-args: |
            VERSION=${{ inputs.version }}

      - name: Purge - Always Docker Build and Push to Harbor ${{ inputs.repo_folder }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: ./purge
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.harbor_addr }}/${{ env.HARBOR_REPO_BASE }}/${{ inputs.repo_folder }}/${{ env.APP_ID_PURGE }}:${{ inputs.version }}
          build-args: |
            VERSION=${{ inputs.version }}

      - name: Migration-Utility - Docker Build and Push to Harbor ${{ inputs.repo_folder }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: ./migration-utility
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.harbor_addr }}/${{ env.HARBOR_REPO_BASE }}/${{ inputs.repo_folder }}/${{ env.APP_ID_MIGRATION_UTILITY }}:${{ inputs.version }}
          build-args: |
            VERSION=${{ inputs.version }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was that the `github.ref_type = branch` instead of tag.  I'll be testing it further.  But I think I'm good

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).